# General questions about Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, terraform

Is it possible to create multiply instances with same terraform script?

If I have already created an instance, how can I create a new without destroying the other one?

For example I have an instance in AWS and it's connected to Chef Server, when I'm running terraform destroy it deletes everything in AWS but in Chef Server the instance is still visible, is it possible to tell terraform delete it from Chef Server as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Terraform [chef provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/chef.html) has a "recreate_client" option that can be set to true:

> **recreate_client (boolean)** - (Optional) If true, first delete any
>   existing Chef Node and Client before registering the new Chef Client.

Hope this helps

---

### Update 1

Found an old rejected issue [Chef-1867](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1867) that asks for an auto-delete feature in Chef. A suggested work-around was a script that deletes nodes if they don't check-in within a specified time period.

---

### Update 2

Terraform allows you to specify a [destroy time provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html). I haven't tested it, but you could try something like the following:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "knife node delete -y ${var.instance_name}; knife client delete -y ${var.instance_name}"
    when = "destroy"
    on_failure = "continue"
  }
}
```

Personally I don't like the additional complexity this brings to my terraform template (and additional logic to test). I think a periodic chef server purge is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply. I meant only destroy the instance without a recreation.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that it's not possible to delete from Chef Server (as it does for AWS) while running `terraform destroy`, to bad.

Comment: @SlavaAntonenko Answer updated, actually it is possible :-)

Comment: I redacted the example script from update 1 as it isn't safe to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!
Do you have any idea about the other two questions?

Comment: I found an answer for them, I have posted an example.
If I would like to run same script on two different landscape, is it possible to write it modular?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that adding count property which defines number of instances, will do the trick. For example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "name" {
  ami                         = "${var.ami}"
  count                       = 1
  disable_api_termination     = false
  instance_type               = "${var.instance_flavor["server_type"]}"
  subnet_id                   = "${var.aws_network["subnet"]}"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${aws_security_group.name.id}"]
  key_name                    = "${var.instance_key["name"]}"

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.instance_flavor["server_tag_name"]}"
    Description = "Name"
  }
}
```